# This topic ASP.Net mvc is struggeling me

Tags: ora-01000

I am trying to run my ASP.NET MVC application but it is not running would you be kind to let me understand what I did wrong, thanks. 
Model

```
namespace Mytest.Models {   
   public class ProductsListViewMode   {
       public IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; set; }
       public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
       public string CurrentCategory { get; set; }  
   } 
}
```

Controller

```
public ViewResult List(string categoryStr,int page = 1)
{
   try
   {
     ProductsListViewModel model = new ProductsListViewModel{
       Products = repository.Products
       .Where(p => categoryStr == null || p.CategoryInfo == categoryStr)
       .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
       .Skip((page - 1) * PageSize)
       .Take(PageSize),
       PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
       {
          CurrentPage = page,
          ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
          TotalItems = categoryStr == null ?
          repository.Products.Count() :
          repository.Products.Where(c=>c.CategoryInfo==categoryStr).Count()
       },
       CurrentCategory = categoryStr
     };
     return View(model);//These change
   }
   catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
   {
     return View(model:ex);
   }
}
```

and @view

```
@model Mytest.Models.ProductsListViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Products";
 }
 @foreach (var p in Model.Products)
 {  
    Html.RenderPartial("ProductSummary",p);
 }<hr/>
 <div class="pager">
   @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x=>Url.Action("List", new{page=x,    categoryStr=Model.CurrentCategory}))
 </div>
```

These are the error messages

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.InvalidOperationException', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'LeoSaFashion.Models.ProductsListViewModel'.] 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value)+175 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary)+107 
System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData)+49 
System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)+99 
System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)+107 
System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)+291 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)+13 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)+56 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)+420 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)+52 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()+173 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+100
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()+49 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+27 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)+13 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+29 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()+49 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+36 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller)+12 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+22 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()+49 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+26 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+10 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)+21 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+29 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()+49 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)+28 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)+9   
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()+9748493 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)+48 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)+159
```

Comment: You have an exception in the `try` block. The `catch` block then returns different model from the one expected by the page

Comment: When I get rid of the try and catch expression another error message appear: at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is because you return "View(model:ex)" from your catch block. Please debug your code and check why an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to pass an *exception* to your view:

```
return View(model:ex);
```

But, as the error states, the view isn't expecting an exception.  It's expecting a specific model:

```
@model Mytest.Models.ProductsListViewModel
```

So it appears that an attempt to handle an error is itself causing an error.  The question then really becomes:

> How do you *want* to handle an error?

Do you really want to return the view but without any data?  Do you want to redirect to an error page?  Log the error in some way?  Something else?

Ultimately you need to decide specifically what you want to do in order to handle an error.  You can even rely on the framework to direct to an error page for you and simply not handle it yourself at all.  (There are a *variety* of options available to you here, a Google search for "ASP .NET MVC error handling" will yield many articles and examples.)

*Then*, once you are meaningfully handling the error, you're half-way there.  At *that* point you need to find out what that error was in the first place and begin to correct *that* error.

Comment: When I get rid of the try and catch expression another error message appear: at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate at System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest providerManifest, String name) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) at System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.....

Comment: @journa: That would be the exception that was triggering the `catch` block that was causing the problem in your original question.  This sounds like it would make a good new question, to include the entire exception (at least the message and the stack trace) as well as an indication of specifically where it happens.  Note that you have a fairly involved single line of code there.  A good idea for debugging would be to break it apart into multiple operations to narrow down specifically which operation is failing.